# Security rules for updates in Firestore

Tags: security, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

In the realtime database when an update is called on a single value the security rules will evaluate the values present in the database if it is not specified within the request.

In Firestore we have to create rules for the data already present in Firestore `resource.data`, or the data in the request `request.resource.data`.

This causes you to have to replicate your security rules with an or condition to check for present data so that an individual value can be updated.

What is the best way to structure security rules to specify a single condition for each of a set of datas values while still allowing an update on an individual piece of that data?

```
match /subscriptions/{uid} {
    allow read: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    allow write: if request.auth.uid == uid                     
        && request.resource.data.keys().hasAll(['allowedTerminals', 'activeTerminals'])
        && request.resource.data.allowedTerminals is int && request.resource.data.allowedTerminals > 0
        && request.resource.data.activeTerminals is int;
}
```

Given this security rule I could successfully create a new subscription when I initially provide both `activeTerminal` and `allowedTerminal` values, but if I wanted to update the `activeTerminal` value I would have to provide the `allowedTerminal` value as well or the update would return a permission denied error.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior between the Realtime Database and Firestore is actually very similar:

```
data == resource.data             // data in the database
newData == request.resource.data  // data in the incoming request
```

The main difference is that Firestore offers granular operations:

```
allow get, list; // same as allow read;
allow create, update, delete; // same as allow write;
```

It's likely that you'll want to have separate rules for `create`, `update`, and `delete`:

```
allow create: if isMyCustomObject(request.resource.data);
allow update: if isUpdateToMyCustomObject(request.resource.data);
allow delete: if ...
```

You can read more about this in [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/secure-data#secure_writes) (sorry that part got pushed so far down!)

Comment: So in Firestore we have to write separate rules for each operation even though we want to apply the same rule to the value. This doesn't seem to be very DRY. I know they are promising performance improvements and the ability to query on multiple fields under Firestore but I'm not sure this outweighs the maintenance this would inject into an application especially since firebase gives no indication of which rules are failing when permission is denied. I see this being a nightmare in a large scale application.

Comment: In Firestore you *can* write separate rules for each operation. Often you'll have different authorization requirements for each operation, and thus that's desirable. I believe your point is more, "while authorization requirements may change, I always want to enforce my schema independent of those requirements", no? Similar to the ".validate" rule in the Realtime Database.

Comment: Exactly Mike. It seems that the only way to keep a schema in Firestore is to always pass the entire piece of data you will store, not an individual value. On that point though I am not sure how set or update are much different unless you are using them for permissions rather than to validate data.

Comment: I feel this was an oversight. If I have a document with 20 values stored inside and I want to update a single value in that document I should not have to pass all the document values to update a single value just to enforce a schema.

Comment: `create`, `update`, and `delete` are distinct operations, both from an SDK perspective, as well as a security perspective. For instance: creation might contain several required properties, while update may contain one of several optional properties (and delete, obviously, has no properties).

Enforcing a resource schema would require the use of something like Open API spec (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification) where you have to specify required and optional fields for each resource, on each operation, much like what we do here.

Comment: I don't disagree that there might be better ways to handle this (e.g. have a `firestore.schema` file containing only schema information (Open API spec or other) that is ANDed with the `firestore.rules` file), but I think that it's more powerful and flexible than the Realtime Database language.

Comment: request.resource.data returns // data in the database not // data in the incoming request 
why ????

Comment: Yes, even for the **updates** it seems that `request.resource.data` contains the entire document update, even if we send just a specific field. Why is that so?

Comment: The docs link in @MikeMcDonald's post is 404'ing, this page has an explanation of what the different allowed methods are (get/list/read etc) https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-language